# How to determine the bad schema?

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema, sax

I am writing a small application to validate a "candidate" xml file against a "bank" of known good schema files, which are stored in a folder...

Turns out the known good schema files are raising problems themselves!

The way I load the schema files (21 files, I am pretty sure most of these schemas don't only refer to themselves, but some of them use other schemas in the folder) into my "schema space":

```
// Load schemas into schema space:
        Schema mySchema;
        try {
            SchemaFactory mySchemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            mySchemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver(pathToSchemasFolder));
            mySchema = mySchemaFactory.newSchema(primeAllSchemaDocsFromFolder(pathToSchemasFolder));
            System.out.println("Schemas loaded");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Schema loading failed: " + e);
        }
```

I am getting:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Schema loading failed: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 232; columnNumber: 5; s4s-elt-chara...`

- Notice it gives me line number and column number but not file name...

I am already using a custom `XsdErrorHandler()` when I validate:

```
// Validate xml file within schema space:
        try {
            Validator validator = mySchema.newValidator();
            validator.setErrorHandler(new XsdErrorHandler());
            validator.validate(getSingleXmlFileStreamSource(pathToXmlCandidateFile));
            System.out.println("Validation is successful");
```

But, upon debug, I see that this doesn't get invoked... It makes sense, since the part that's failing is loading the schemas, something done before I set the ErrorHandler to the Validator...

I wonder if there's a way to set an error handler for the schema loading process?

Or any other technique you can please share with me to find the offending schema's name?
(like: add the schema files into the schema space incrementally, test each time that the schema space is valid - without any invalid schema defitions)

Comment: So what's the error that you've redacted and replaced by ellipses?

Comment: "Schema loading failed: org.xml.sax.SAXException: [Error] line nr: 232 column nr: 5 message: s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'A

    '." - I don't really care about the error, I am sure there are plenty more where that came from! I was able to find the offending schema by removing schemas (manual binary search) until the error changed... I am interested in an automated way of knowing the offending schema file

Comment: What type of `Source` you give to the `SchemaFactory.newSchema` method?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Source[] - this is generated by my method, which takes a folder path and, for each xsd file in that folder, it creates a new StreamSource (from the FileInputStream of each file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your `StreamSource`s you should provide a `publicId` property. This property does not influence the parsing, but provides useful information in the exceptions:

```
     * <p>The public identifier is always optional: if the application
     * writer includes one, it will be provided as part of the
     * location information.</p>
```

If you use the schema file name as `publicId`, you'll be able to retrieve it from the [SAXParseException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html).

---

Edit from original asker:
Since I am using Source[] in newSchema(), I can prepare the input for each Source to include the mentioned method, like so:

```
 Source[] sourceArray = new Source[numberOfSchemaFiles];
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfSchemaFiles ; i++) {
        String currentFileName = schemaFiles[i].getName();
        try {
            StreamSource currentStreamSource = new StreamSource(
                    new FileInputStream(directoryPath + currentFileName)
            );
            currentStreamSource.setPublicId(currentFileName);
            sourceArray[i] = currentStreamSource;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find file: " + directoryPath + currentFileName);
        }
```

Comment: I don't have setPublicId() at that point, but I do have setSystemId() and it seems to get the job done! I am able this way to see the offending schema file! Do you think I should stay with setSystemId(), or I should try and understand how to be able to access setPublicId()?

Comment: `setPublicId` is specific to `StreamSource`, but you can also use `setSystemId` giving the absolute path of the schema file.

Comment: I actually took a look into my code and found that I am setting Source = StreamSource and Source doesn't have setPublicId()... I added an extra step to prepare StreamSource nicely before loading up into the Source array :) THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Are you an assistant professor in Uniwersytet Gdański? My partner is from Gdinya :) Can I reach out to you on LinkedIn with an idea that may be interesting to you?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method SchemaFactory.setErrorHandler() that allows you to intercept errors during schema compilation.

Comment: yes. I set my error handler to the custom one I am using. I tried getting all sorts: exception.getSystemId()... getPublicId()... Both are null at this point... Would you know how to link from the exception back to the file causing it? I mean, it does state the line. So, I am sure it knows *something* about the bad source?

Comment: You've supplied a `Source` object that wraps an anonymous input stream. If you supply a `Source` that wraps a `File` rather than a `FileInputStream`, or if you pass a `SystemId` as a second argument to the constructor, then this will appear in the diagnostics.

Comment: In fact the absence of the systemId might not just result in poor diagnostics, it might be the cause of the error. To resolve relative references between schema modules in xs:include or xs:iimport, the processor needs to know the location (base URI) of the module, and it can't know this if all you supply is an InputStream, which contains no information about where it came from.

Comment: this is pure gold! I shall wrap FIle's instead of FIS. Hopefully, this prevents some errors - thanks!